# Lustre Client on Linux Kernel 4+

Tags: lustre

Does anyone know if it is possible to install lustre client software on a linux machine that has kernel 4+? From what I have experimented so far, all the working examples are on kernel 3.10. And if I try to install kmod-luster-client on 4+ machine, it fails with:

> rpm -ivh kmod-lustre-client-2.10.5-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
>
> error: Failed dependencies:
>           kernel < 3.10.0-863 is needed by kmod-lustre-client-2.10.5-1.el7.x86_64
>           kernel(PDE_DATA) = 0x44f0d59d is needed by kmod-lustre-client-2.10.5-1.el7.x86_64

Comment: I am able to make it work on AWS using ALinux 2 which has lustre kernel module installed by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `lustre/ChangeLog` in the b2_10 branch, it works with kernels at least 4.4.133-94.33 (SLES12SP3) and 4.4.0-131 (Ubuntu 16.04).

If you are using a newer kernel, you also need to use a newer version of Lustre.  The `lustre/ChangeLog` on the tip of master (almost 2.12 release) reports support for kernels 4.15.0-32 (Ubuntu 18.04).

It looks like you are trying to install a binary kernel module RPM built for the RHEL7 kernel on a non-RHEL kernel.  That is never going to work.  You need to either get the right RPMs/Debs for your kernel from https://lustre.org/download/ or download the source and rebuild it for your kernel.

The 2.10.x kernels are currently the LTS maintained releases (bugfixes backported to that release), while 2.11.0 is a feature release that does not have bugfixes backported.